# Query that joins 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

```
CREATE TABLE User(uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,address VARCHAR(40),city 
VARCHAR(20),state VARCHAR(20),
```

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT User.uid, Job.jobid, Protein.pid FROM User
JOIN Job ON (Job.uid = User.uid)
JOIN Protein ON (Job.pid = Protein.pid)
```

I can't figure out how to find a job that utilizes all proteins.

Comment: How are the jobs associated with the proteins. As jobs are related to proteins with a many-to-many relationship, you probably need to create a join table called job_protein to identify which proteins a specific job references.

Comment: you don't have relationship for your `Protein` table

Comment: by all proteins, you mean every single entry in the protein table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the job_ids of every job that has one of every protein in the protein table, and only one of every protein in the protein table

```
select j.job_id
  from job j
    inner join job_proteins p
      on j.job_id = p.jid
  group by j.job_id
    having group_concat(p.pid order by p.pid asc) = 
      (select group_concat(pid order by pid asc) from protein);
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/febf6/5

It was necessary to add an extra table in order to represent the relationship between job, and protein, which was missing from your original schema definition

If it is true that a job can never use more than one of the same protein, then the following query is also sufficient:

```
select j.job_id, count(j.job_id)
  from job j
    inner join job_proteins p
      on j.job_id = p.jid
  group by j.job_id
    having count(j.job_id) = (select count(pid) from protein);
```

Updated demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/febf6/9

Note the updated demo returns the sample job with the same protein listed twice - hence the requirement that a job can't use more than one of the same protein.

If a job can use the same protein more than once, but that's okay and you want to include it in the results of jobs that use all proteins at least once, this query will suffice:

```
select j.job_id, count(j.job_id)
  from job j
    inner join job_proteins p
      on j.job_id = p.jid
  group by j.job_id
    having count(distinct p.pid) = (select count(pid) from protein);
```

Comment: what is group_concat?

Comment: It's a mysql function that concatenates a group of results into a string. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat. eg in the subselect, instead of returning a row for every pid, it returns just a string that looks like `"1,2,3,...N"` where N is the last pid in the table

Comment: So this query would get the jobs that utilize every single protein?

Comment: yes. run the demo and play with it to make sure it meets your requirements

Comment: @BobblyFillay is it possible for a job to use the same protein twice? if not, we can use a different query